# Get work on custom solo mining software

Tags: json-rpc, solo-mining, mining-software, getwork

I'm making a bitcoin solo miner, what is the URL to get the current block header a with JSON call? I also need the URL where the work will be sent if a valid solution is found.

Right now I'm trying to understand how the solo mining process works. From what I've found on the internet, to get and receive data from the bitcoin network I need to make some JSON calls, but I don't know the URL and the format. If I understand correctly, this is how I think the miner works:

1. Get header from the network
2. Find the nonce that makes the header hash to a low enough value
3. Send the data out to the network
4. If the nonce is correct get paid

Am I correct? Are there any tutorials or can someone give me an explanation of how this process works?

Comment: Welcome to the bitcoin stack exchange! If you need help getting familiarized, there's the [help center](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help) and the [tour](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/tour). In order for you to get the help you need, I would suggest adding some more detail to your post, such as how your current setup is configured and what you have tried already.

Comment: So I need a detailed explanation ( or links to examples ) of how it works in theory for each step I mentioned.( except step 2, I know how that works )

I haven't started to code the miner yet, I'll do that after I know exactly what I'm doing

Comment: This is a complete implementation of a getwork miner: https://github.com/jgarzik/pyminer

Comment: related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12603/the-bitcoin-mining-algorithm-from-a-programmers-viewpoint